# php muestra � en lugar de la ñ

Tags: php, html, mysql, php7

tengo este problema con php ya que al traer de la base de datos mis valores al querer mostrar la ñ me arroja � en la base de datos si se muestra el carácter como es pero al querer traerlo y mostrarlo con php no es asi, mi base de datos si esta configurada para usar uft-8, tambien especifique en el head de html los caracteres de uft-8 y además lo hice con php, les dejo el código por si me podrirán ayudar:
esta es la parte de la tabla la estoy "dibujando" en un ciclo while para mostar mas datos

```
                                include('my_function.php');
                                $currency = getCurrency();
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalogo ORDER BY codigo ASC";
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                $i = 1;
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' name='codigo[]' value='".$row['codigo']."' readonly ></td>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' name='producto[]' value='".$row['nombre']."' readonly ></td>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' name='familia[]' value='".$row['departamento']."' readonly  ></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value=".$row['existencia']. " name='region' readonly  ></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$cantidad' placeholder='0' name='ExistenciasSucursal[]' required></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$precio' placeholder='$0' name='PrecioSucursal[]' required></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$sucursal'  placeholder='' name='Sucursal[]' required></td>";
                                    echo "</tr> ";
```

también tengo que mencionar que esta tabla esta dentro de un form por que envía datos por lo tanto agregue esto al código `<form action="asignar_productos_sucursal.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">` ademas en mi head del html puse lo siguiente:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1″ />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

y dentro de mi etiqueta php agregue esto:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: si lo vi hace poco, aplique lo que dice ahí pero no parece solucionar mi problema

Comment: revisa que al momento de crear la conexion estas aceptando el charset utf-8, ejemplo `$mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");` y en tu cotejamiento de la tabla usar tambien utf8_spanish_ci

Comment: Intenta modificar tu etiqueta meta por la siguiente: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` . tener en cuenta que debe estar en al cabecera entre `<head>` y `</head>` .